# C++ Record from two microphones

Tags: c++, microphone, recording

For research purposes, I am trying to record from 2 microphones at the same time, but to no avail.

Is there a library I can use to record from 2 or more microphones? I have 2 USB microphones connected to COM4 and COM5 of my PC, but I can't find a library/reference, that allows me to choose the device I am recording with.

Any idea on how I should approach such thing then?

Comment: What platform? On windows the standard audio libraries certainly allow for this.

Comment: Yes, windows. I didn't see any such option. Can you name a library you know that can do it?

Comment: Firstly, try [SoftwareRecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as this question is off topic in its current form. However, some initial insight: on Windows, ASIO is going to be your best bet for low-latency recording, and currently ASIO only supports one device at a time (without some _very_ [low level hacks](https://github.com/Qix-/cbind)). If the hardware is a bus, then you're far better off as it will allow you to record using two audio inputs. You can then use [simple audio software](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Multichannel_Recording) to record multiple inputs at once.

Comment: @Qix I am not looking for recording software, I am looking for an audio library, that can handle multiple microphones...I have been working with software in the past, but it is just too much work.

Comment: Then you want to use Steinberg's ASIO interface/library with bus (multiple inputs) hardware. Speaking from a considerable amount of experience, multiple streams from two cards is going to be very difficult - at least on Windows.

Comment: Doesn't ASIO support stereo recordings? That probably still counts as a single device, but you'd of course need a proper audio card.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the specifics of what you want to do. Any of the windows core audio APIs can do what you want if you are happy to create a separate capture stream for each device. The drawback to this is that you will have a very hard time synchronising your recordings because there is no built in way in windows to guarantee that the 2 (or more) capture streams start at exactly the same time. This means you have to use other methods to correct for timing post recording. However, if your requirements are more lax then this is a trivially easy thing to setup using DirectSound or the old MME API.

If you need perfectly synchronised recordings, then, as @Qix says, you will not be able to do it using 2 different devices (such as 2 separate usb mics) - at least not without implementing your own driver. ASIO is a very easy interface to use and easy to program for. It will allow you to record perfectly synchronised audio signals from as many sources as your specific ASIO enabled hardware interface supports.